# Registration using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do a very simple registration using AngularJS. 
Firstly, I'm getting user with this e-mail and assign to $scope.users. If method "GetUserByEmail" returns more than one user, I try show message "User already exists". And here is problem. Method GetUserByEmail is avoided. Program "jumps" to "if" condition and $scope.users is always empty, I don't know why. Sometimes after adding user to database, the method returns array of object and assign to $scope.users

It's my code with method CreateUser:

```js
var RegisterController = function ($scope, Api, $http) {

    $scope.users = {
    }

    $scope.CreateUser = function () {
        var user = {
            Password: $scope.password,
            Name: $scope.name,
            Surname: $scope.surname,
            Email: $scope.email,
            DateOfBirth: $scope.dateofBirth
        }

        Api.GetUserByEmail("Users", "GetUserByEmail", $scope.email).then(function (d) {
                $scope.users = d;
            }); 

        if ($scope.users.length > 0)
        {
            alert("User already exists!");
            $scope.users = {};
        }
        else
        {
            Api.PostUser("Users", "PostUser", user).then(function (d) {
                alert("Hello");
            });
        }


    };
}

RegisterController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Api', '$http'];
```

And method GetUserByEmail:

```js
this.GetUserByEmail = function (controllerName, methodName, email) {
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/' + controllerName + '/' + methodName  + '?email=' + email,
            config: {
                params: {
                    "email": email
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function onSuccess(response) {
            return response.data;
        },
        function onError(response) {
            return response.statusText;
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used success...error block on your request, eventhough the response is null, request will return into success block and you can validate yor data. I think these are fine you.

```
var RegisterController = function ($scope, Api, $http) {

    $scope.users = {
    }

    $scope.CreateUser = function () {
        var user = {
            Password: $scope.password,
            Name: $scope.name,
            Surname: $scope.surname,
            Email: $scope.email,
            DateOfBirth: $scope.dateofBirth
        }

        Api.GetUserByEmail("Users", "GetUserByEmail", $scope.email).success(function (response) {
                 if (response!=null && dresponse.lenght > 0)
        {
            alert("User already exists!");
            $scope.users = {};
        }
        else
        {
               Api.PostUser("Users", "PostUser", user)
                 .success(function (d) {
                  alert("Hello");
            }).error(function(e){
            console.log(e.message);
            });
        }
            }).error(function(error){
                console.log(error.message);
            }); 
    };
}

RegisterController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Api', '$http'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!!!

```js
var RegisterController = function($scope, Api, $http) {

  $scope.users = {}

  $scope.CreateUser = function() {
    var user = {
      Password: $scope.password,
      Name: $scope.name,
      Surname: $scope.surname,
      Email: $scope.email,
      DateOfBirth: $scope.dateofBirth
    }

    Api.GetUserByEmail("Users", "GetUserByEmail", $scope.email).then(function(d) {
      $scope.users = d;
      if ($scope.users.length > 0) {
        alert("User already exists!");
        $scope.users = {};
      } else {
        Api.PostUser("Users", "PostUser", user).then(function(d) {
          alert("Hello");
        });
      }
    });

  };
}

RegisterController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Api', '$http'];
```